# Is the 'main' function classified as a function definition in C?

Tags: c, function-declaration

Is the 'main' function classified as a function definition in C?

The reason I am asking is I have been presented with a piece of code and when explaining the difference between the function declarations at the top of the code and the function definitions at the bottom, I was asked if the 'main' function is also considered a function definition or if it is considered as something else (as main functions are essential unlike other functions).

Comment: Please clarify the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a hosted implementation of C (the normal sort), the only novel features of `main()` compared to any other function are:

- It is where the program execution starts.
- It does not have to be pre-declared.
- If execution reaches the `}` at the end, it behaves as if there was a `return 0;` before the `}`**<sup>*</sup>**.

In all other respects, `main()` is a normal function.  It can be called recursively in C (whereas a C++ program cannot call its `main()` recursively).

Since a function is defined when its body is specified, when you write `int main(void) { … }` or `int main(int argc, char **argv) { … }` or any alternative, you are defining the function because the braces are present so the function body is defined.

**<sup>*</sup>** <sup>See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for some minor caveats about the `return 0;` statement if the return type is not compatible with `int`.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Main is a function like all the rest. Just has a different semantics and different requirements.

The semantics being it is the start of the program.

The requirements it has a predefined set of signatures

Comment: You misunderstood. I am not asking if it is a function, I am asking if the 'main' code can be considered as a function definition.

Comment: _I was asked if the 'main' function is also considered a function definition or if it is considered as something else_ - I answered this bit

Comment: You still do not quite follow. I must have phrased it badly. See Jonathan Leffler's post for the answer I was looking for

Comment: @ThomasHollis-- "Main is a function like all the rest." I believe that the point was that a function is defined when its body is specified, and `main()` is no different in this respect. This answers the question, albeit in a slightly laconic manner.

Comment: It was rather a bit to the point. Thanks for the expansion of the meaning of the statement